# JUnit Event Listner Testing

Tags: junit, spring-data-jpa, entitylisteners

I'm using @EntityListner with the @PostPersist annotation and @PostUpdate, I'm in a project that uses the tdd technique and I have to develop a unit test for the covrage and I do not know how to do it, possible to to have help so that I can start ??
thank you in advance

Comment: It depends on what you do in your `PrePersist` / `PostUpdate` code. Maybe you can mock a logic of this method as an external dependency, or maybe you need to write an integration test, where you run an entire JPA context (for example by the use of `@DataJpaTest` annotation). In this test, you can read entity after persisting and check it states. 
Can you show this code?

Comment: the problem was that when calling the class by @EntityListner (Service.class), we can not inject an object in the class Service because spring context does not take it into account as the call to a class by .class is equivalent to putting Service service = new Service (); therefore the context can not inject the object.
Thank you for your comment anyway